# Получение события кластеризации в OpenLayers

Tags: cluster, openlayers

Как узнать и получить спрятанные (кластеризованные) feature после кластеризации в OpenLayers?

Comment: может слой со всеми фичами не удалять а прятать ?

Comment: feature отображаются в кластеры с помощью механизма кластеризации - OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster, что он там с ними делает я не знаю (прячет или удаляет), мне необходимо знать когда и с какими объектами он это делает.

Comment: ну я вот посмотрел их сэмпл, там ViewLayer.remove(),  почему бы полный слой не хранить отдельно и не показывать, когда фильтрация отсутствует ?